# angularjs Restful app issue for ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I was trying to implement a basic crud operations in angularjs.

However I am unable to do so as my ng-click is not working.

my list.html is as follows:-

```
  <div class="container">
          <input type="text" ng-controller="Remove">

            <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="person in people | filter: {age: search}" class="row-{{$first}} | orderBy: 'name'">
                {{person.name}} ,  {{person.age}} 
                <a ng-click="edit(person.name)" >edit</a> 
                <a ng-click="remove(person.name)" >X</a>
                <span ng-show="$first">First</span>
                <span ng-show="$middle">Middle</span>
                <span ng-show="$last">Last</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

my app.js file is as below:-

```
angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute'])
    .config(function( $routeProvider){
      $routeProvider
      .when('/',{
        templateUrl: 'list.html',
        controller: 'Ctrl'
      })
      .when('/edit/:id',{
        templateUrl: 'edit.html',
        controller: 'Edit'
      })
      .when('/add',{
        templateUrl: 'add.html',
        controller: 'Add'
      })
     .when('/remove',{
        templateUrl: 'remove.html',
        controller: 'Remove'
      })

    .when('/login',{
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      })
}) 
// end of config --routes

    .run(function($rootScope){
          $rootScope.people =[
              {
                name: "Johna", 
                age: 23
              },
              {
                name: "Shamit",
                age: 74
              },
              {
                name: "Prath",
                age: 20
              },
              {
                name: "Surya",
                age: 28
              },
              {
                name: "Hari",
                age: 13
              }
            ];
})
    .controller('Ctrl',['$scope','$rootScope',function(scope,$rootScope){
       // console.log(scope);
            scope.addStatus = true;
            scope.name = "Rafal";
            scope.age = "28";
            scope.persons=['Tom', 'Jerry']; 

//          scope.remove = function(index){
//             scope.people.splice(index, 1);
//          };

          scope.save = function(){
            scope.addStatus = true;
            scope.person = [];
          };

    }])
    .controller('Edit',['$scope','$rootScope','$routeParams',function(scope,$rootScope,$routeParams){
        scope.edit = function(index){
            console.log("The first edit");
            scope.addStatus = false;
            scope.person = $rootScope.people[$routeParams.id];
          };   

    }])
    .controller('Add',['$scope','$rootScope',function($scope,$rootScope){
         $scope.add = function(){
            $rootScope.people.push($scope.person);
             console.log($scope.person)
            $scope.person ={};
          };
    }])

    .controller('Remove',function($scope,$rootScope){
      $scope.people=$rootScope.people;   
      $scope.remove = function(name){
            var index = getSelectedIndex(name);
            alert(index)
             $rootScope.people.splice(index, 1);
          };

    })



  //The below is for login basic controller..check below

    .controller("LoginCtrl",["$scope",'Auth',function($scope,Auth){

  console.log("heyy")

  $scope.login = function(){

     Auth.signin({
      email:$scope.email,
      password:$scope.password  
    })
  };

   $scope.register = function(){

    Auth.signup({
      email:$scope.email,
      password:$scope.password  
    })

  };

}]);

  function getSelectedIndex(name){
        for(var i=0;i<$rootScope.people.length;i++)
            if($rootScope.people[i].name==name)
                console.log(name);
                return i;
        return -1;
    };

//});
```

I am not able to trigger ng-click and hence not able to edit and delete from the page.
Please help me with this situation.

Comment: your edit function is not in scope of Remove controller

Comment: First, you don't have to define `ng-controller` in your HTML when you have a controller defined in the route.  Second, why would you have `ng-controller="Remove"` in the `list` HTML? And lastly, `ng-click` calls functions that are defined in the `$scope` of the controller you currently have loaded, which means that the `add` button will only work on the `Add` view, the way your code is structured currently.

Comment: Creating individual controller for particular action is not good idea. Try to merge Add, Edit and Remove into single controller.

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers I merged the edit action into the list controller..But the click action is not triggering

Comment: a lot of your code is WRONG. `controller('Ctrl',['$scope','$rootScope',function(scope,$rootScope){` and in the controller you use `scope.`. You need to put `$` before every scope everywhere ! (expect in directive link )

Comment: @AlainIb I understand the conventions but was just checking because I am assigning $scope to a function parameter and using it..Dont see an issue with it..Please let me know if I am going wrong since I can improve myself

Comment: in some controller you use $scope and in another you use just scope. use alsways $scope ( as you use $rootscope )

Comment: `I am assigning $scope to a function parameter and using it`. where ?  anyway you can make `$scope.save = .. ` or `$scope.save = function($scope.XXX) ` without problem

Answer (score 1):

for "anchor" tags href is mandatory in order to make it clickable.

we can use href="#" / href="javascript:void(0)" for dummy links

use like this

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="edit(person.name)">edit</a> 
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="remove(person.name)">X</a>
```

In this case "javascript:void(0)" is recommended because it won't cause problems with ngroute / ui-route

And also Move the `$scope.edit` and `$scope.remove` methods to `Ctrl` controller

Comment: this is only partially correct.  `href` is necessary to make the link be visibly styled as a link, but ng-click will still work even if the href is absent. http://plnkr.co/edit/znSQPEpL8VpWE0KsDKP9?p=preview